# How to get leaflet.js map working with jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, leaflet

I have been trying to get leaflet.js maps working with my jquery mobile project.  It sort of works but not at all what it should be. The map is not sized correctly and does not zoom in and out correctly.

I followed the docs here:

[leafletjs.com](http://leafletjs.com/)

I also found this jsfiddle that works finding your geolocation:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/AQaCJ/)

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#index', function(){  
    var map = L.map('map');

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 16,
        attribution: 'Example made by <a href="http://www.gajotres.net">Gajotres</a>'
    }).addTo(map);

    map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
    map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);

    map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 18}); 

function onLocationFound(e) {
    var radius = e.accuracy / 2;

    L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();

    L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
}

function onLocationError(e) {
    alert(e.message);
}

});
```

I made two changes in the js code according to the docs is this jsfiddle.  It is supposed to be a map of Puerto Vallarta Mexico. It sort of works but doesn't really.
[my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fatfantasma/7kve593q/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    **// Changed this line**
    var map = L.map('map').setView([20.602237, -105.236859],15);  // Puerta Vallarta South Side

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 16,
        attribution: 'Example made by <a href="http://www.gajotres.net">Gajotres</a>'
    }).addTo(map);

    map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
    map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);

    **//Removed the below line**
    //map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 18});   


function onLocationFound(e) {
    var radius = e.accuracy / 2;

    L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();

    L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
}

function onLocationError(e) {
    alert(e.message);
}

});
```

**Edit**
My jsfiddle now works in jsfiddle by replacing

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#page_map_south_side', function(){
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

However, this does not change anything in my actual code.  I believe .on('pageinit') line just doesn't work in jsfiddle properly.  So I am really back to square one.

I change the line to set the location to Puerto Vallarta and remove the geo location line of code.

Does anybody have any ideas why it's not working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able get the maps working by initiating the map with

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#page_map_south_side', function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

You're initiating you `map` this way

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#index', function(){})
```

Instead of this try initializing it this way

```
$(document).ready(function(){})
```

Here is working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zafrii/3gtgqmmd/)

Comment: Although your answer works in jsfiddle now it doesn't actually work in my code.  I believe your answer only compensates for a jsfiddle problem.  I have edited the question and fixed my jsfiddle.  There must be something else going on jQM or my CSS.  I'm not sure where to look. suggestions?

Comment: @fatfantasma If your purpose is just to prepare the map for mobile, why are you using **JQM**? I mean [here](http://leafletjs.com/examples/mobile.html) is an offical example, but they are not using **JQM** there, try this